# Put & post method for a blob on azure returning 404 The specified resource does not exist.

Tags: azure, post, postman, azure-blob-storage, put

I am new to software development & IT. I am working on a proof of concept with Azure. I am trying to work with Postman to send a PUT or POST request to a blob I have on Azure.  I was able to successfully use a GET.

When I do a PUT or POST, Postman returns a 404 status that the specified resource does not exist. I think I set up the access policy correctly. I understand I may need a shared access signature. Where would I put that or how to I configure it in Postman?

Please let me know what you think.  Thank you.

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have set the [required headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#request-headers-all-blob-types) like `x-ms-date` and `x-ms-blob-type` and that you use the **PUT** verb. You pass your credentials using the `Authorization` header. See:

[Authorization for the Azure Storage Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorization-for-the-azure-storage-services)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where do I add the required headers like x-ms-date and x-ms-blob-type?  Which authorization type do I use?